# Sudo Apt get update throwing weird error about ubuntu disco Release

Tags: apt, updates, software-sources

Everytime I run sudo apt-get update I get the following error:

```
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Reading package lists... Done       
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This is my sources.list file

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 19.04 _Disco Dingo_ - Release amd64 (20190416)]/ disco main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
# deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
# deb-src https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports universe multiverse main restricted
```

OS Info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

I have looked at other posts on here and some are similar but none of them are specific to this Release. Please let me know what you think. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing weird about it: Your sources.list file has two active disco sources. Disable them, then run `sudo apt update` because your sources have changed.

Comment: @user535733 which ones are they?

Comment: They are the two lines that 1) Have the word 'disco' in them, and 2) Lack the disabling `#` at the beginning of the line. Obviously, you must use a text editor to add the `#` in order to disable those lines.

Comment: You should make your answer into an actual answer so I can accept it as the answer

Comment: Are you confident about HOW to disable those lines?

Comment: Yeah, add a # before the two lines that have disco in them (that are not already commented out), then save the file then run sudo apt-get update

Comment: You are confident about how to edit a file that's owned by root?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107160/discussion-between-pa-gw-and-user535733).